# How to deal with people that never accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, accept-rate, unaccepted-answer

I just came across some OP that has about 20 questions with good answers (in my opinion).
But he/she never took the time to accept any of those answers.

In the "Old" days we had the acceptance %, and many people would comment on that.
But that is gone now.
So what what is the recommended action?

- Do we still comment on the questions of these OP saying "please improve your accept rate"?
- Do we ignore it?
- Any other recommended action?

Comment: What does it matter if there is no accepted answer? Is the top voted answer not good enough?

Comment: Ignore it. You cannot force the questioner to accept an answer. It is best to move on.

Comment: Regarding your first point, no we don't. And we didn't. In fact, those comments were nuke-able with a single flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore it. Forcing someone to accept the answer is not a good practice.

Moreover, it doesn't really matter if the question has an accepted answer or not. If a question receives atleast 1 upvoted answer it is considered as answered.

And there is community voting which makes sure that the best answer floats to the top.

So, just ignore it and move on.

Comment: What if someone want to catch Jon Skeet. Without "accepted answer's point" only Jon Skeet can catch himself. So should we think race is over!!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: We should never force someone to accept the answer. If there is a new user, then it might be acceptable to let him know that if one of the answers solves his problem, then he may accept the answer by clicking on the Checkmark - in order to guide him through the site and make him aware about the features. But otherwise, I would never ask someone to consider accepting answers. Providing good quality answers, asking good and well-researched questions, helping a new user get accustomed to site should be more important than surpassing Jon Skeet. He is already 500k+!

Comment: IMHO, the points/rep system is also a motivation to answer questions. Personally, if someone takes the time out to reply to my question, courtesy demands that that person be thanked and accepting their answer is simply acknowledging their effort. It would be nice to have an automated system to inform 'new' users about this as, I guess, the crux of the issue might be that new users are simply not aware of this feature.

Comment: How about if there's a bounty from other people?

Answer (score 4):

> - Do we still comment on the questions of these OP saying "please improve your accept rate"?
> - Do we ignore it?
> - Any other recommended action?

You already know that accept rate is gone now. Do you know why? Because we don't want anyone to focus on someone's accept rate and keep his/her *precious* eyes on problems of the OP. So best advice. **Ignore it**.

Comment: @NullPonyPointer - Hmm I said the same.